# Best Practice for Storing Many Client-Side Javascript Static Variables

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

I have an application in which everything is accomplished, preferably, on the client side.  JavaScript on the client side will determine the country location of the user using geolocation.  Afterwards, however, the client application needs to perform calculations based upon what country the user is from.  I have a list of variables for each country - UK:176 - for example - how should I deliver these variables to the client?

One thing crossing my mind was to store the data in hidden html tables, that the JavaScript could fetch based upon country later.  However, that solution is very hacky.  And obviously having some 200+ JS variables would harm performance.  Is local web storage a good alternative, for example?

Comment: Why not use cookies?

Comment: Server config is strange, there can't be communication back and forth, so the workaround I'm trying to find is simply sending every possible variable with the original html response, so JavaScript can handle everything else client side.  The current config is essentially just a fancy file server, so everything- variables and what not- needs to be packaged in the first response

Comment: "Lists of variables"? Uh oh. Use data structures such as objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to store the variables on the client side, yes, then local web storage is probably the best way to go. If you don't need the data persistent you could also store the variables in the session storage. As the name implies, this store is lost if the user closes the session (closing the tab or browser).

Comment: The one issue I have with localstorage, is does everything need to be accessed through the API?  Is it possible to initialize a document with all my static variables that will be shipped with the response, and automatically populate the localstorage, for example?  Instead of having hundreds of lines of localstorage.setitem in the JS, which seems unruly

Comment: I would make a function that gets called every time you need your variables. In this function, you check if you have already set your variables (by creating a separate variable for this) and if you don't, set them.